# How to remove an object using handlebars and backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I've poked around google for awhile now, but am having trouble implementing a delete, and soon editing functionality, on a personal, experimental project.

So I have a table populated by a list of 'resources' in my handlebars template:

```
<tbody id="resourceList">
        {{#each models}}
        <tr id="info_{{this.attributes.id}}" style="border-top: solid 1px black;">
            <td width="3%"><button style="background: none; border: none;"><i id="icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></button></td>
            <td id="title" width="67%">{{this.attributes.title}}</td>
            <td width="10%">{{this.attributes.Type}}</td>
            <td width="10%">{{this.attributes.itemsNeeded}}</td>
            <td width="10%">04/05/2014</td>         
        </tr>
        <tr id="expand_{{this.attributes.id}}" style="border-bottom: solid 1px black;">
            <td colspan="5">
                <div id="expand" class="jumbotron" style="margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%;">
                    <div>{{this.attributes.orgName}}</div>
                    <div>{{this.attributes.email}}</div>
                    <div>{{this.attributes.phoneNumber}}</div>
                    <div>{{this.attributes.address}}</div><br>
                    <div>{{this.attributes.description}}</div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 5%; margin-right: 5px;">

                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 5px;" id="delete_post" value="Delete" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
```

This delete button button triggers an event in the view

```
events: {
            "click #submit_post": "create",
            "click #delete_post": "remove"
        },
```

The remove function is where I'm lost. I don't know how I can 'know' which row was selected and pass it over to the view. I tried making the button class="{{this.attributes.id}} so that each one selected would have a class 1,2,3,4....But I don't understand how I can get the class of the selected element. I'm sure this is something really basic, so again, sorry :/

```
remove: function() {

              this.model.destroy();
        }
```

Comment: `remove` should get an event argument, in there you'll find `ev.currentTarget` which is the thing that was clicked; you should be able to backtrack from there to what you need, right?

Comment: ah! it looks like that DOES give me what was clicked :D Do you know how I could get the class of that element?

Comment: I don't see anything interesting in any `class` attributes, am I missing something?

Comment: I recommend using `$.data` to hold data rather than concealing it in your class name.

Comment: There's nothing in the class attribute right now, but I was thinking I could put it {{this.attributes.id}} @muistooshort

Comment: @ncksllvn is right, a `data-whatever` attribute would be better, then you could `$(ev.currentTarget).data('whatever')` to pull it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you it looks like this is going to work!